# What is the difference between reacting and dissolving?

Tags: solutions, terminology

When one chemical is added to another how would we come to know whether the compound dissolves in it or reacts with it? For example $\ce{AgNO3}$ dissolves in $\ce{CCl4}$ whereas it could also have been a double displacement reaction. And what is the major difference between the two  processes at atomic level?

Comment: Dissolving is a type of reaction. Double displacement is a different type of reaction. So something which is dissolving is also reacting.

Comment: @bon Does this mean that new compounds are formed even when one compound dissolves in another?

Comment: @user456 New species may be formed, like solvated ions for instance but these don't count as new compounds.

Comment: @bon that sounds a bit misleading. Dissolving is a physical process, while double displacement is a chemical process. So technically speaking, no new chemical compositions are being made when one substance is dissolved in another.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

CCl4 is a covalent compound (having no free ions). Thus it cannot enter into an ionic reaction/double displacement reaction.

**Basic Requisites for checking reactivity**

- [Reactivity Series](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Reactivity_series) (Elements higher up in the series replace the lower elements)
- [Checking whether bonds are covalent or ionic](http://chemwiki.ucdavis.edu/Theoretical_Chemistry/Chemical_Bonding/Covalent_Bonds_vs_Ionic_Bonds) (You might just need to remember which compounds are which type. Some compounds can have both type of bonds)

**Bonds**

- *Ionic* = "Ionic bonding is a type of chemical bond that involves the electrostatic attraction between oppositely charged ions. These ions represent atoms that have lost one or more electrons (known as cations) and atoms that have gained one or more electrons (known as anions)." [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ionic_bonding)
  Thus the elements can take or give electrons. In a solution they exist as ions.
- *Covalent* = "A covalent bond is a chemical bond that involves the sharing of electron pairs between atoms. These electron pairs are known as shared pairs or bonding pairs and the stable balance of attractive and repulsive forces between atoms when they share electrons is known as covalent bonding." [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Covalent_bond)
  Thus it has no free electrons to give or take.

Comment: Then how does it dissolve in agno3?

Answer (score 0):

As a matter of fact, when we say *dissolve,* it means that when you put something into e.g. water, that chemical might break down into tiny pieces or particles -- you will not be able to see those pieces, and we call this "dissolving".

And on the other hand, when we say *react,* it means that the chemicals  might bond with each other and then produce a new chemical, and this new chemical will then be called as *product* also.

Consider when you mix sugar in the water present in your cup, then you will first see pieces of sugar in a big size, but after you mix the water, then the water will become clean, but the water has turned those pieces of sugar into very tiny pieces that our eyes cannot see.